# How to dynamically change progressbarjs runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Help me please realize one thing please.

I created a simple progressbar.js line under slider. Each slide has various value (timing in seconds) which should pass to progressbar duration.

I take current timing  value with "**.slick-current**" but value doesn't dynamically change in **var bar**. I get only the first value that was received at page loading...

```
  var bar = new ProgressBar.Line("#ProgressBar", {
  strokeWidth: 3,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  color: '#fff',
  trailColor: '#000',
  trailWidth: 1, 
    duration: n, // should dynamically change
    warnings: false, 
    svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'}

});
```

See an example please: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu3ver/Lz71dsut/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I take current timing value with ".slick-current" but value doesn't dynamically change

```
var d = $('.slider .slick-current span').text();
var n = d * 1000;
```

These are "simple types" - string and integer.  They are not dynamically tied to the value of `.slick-current span` - they are set once and stay that value.

You need to update the values just before using them.

```
$(".slick-next, .slick-prev").click(function() {

  d = $('.slider .slick-current span').text();
  n = d * 1000;

  $(document.body).append('timer: ' + d + 'ms');
  bar.set(0);
  bar.animate(1, {
    duration: n

  }, function() {

    $('.slick-next').click();
    $(document.body).append('timer: ' + d + 'ms');
  });

});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oue8sgq6/